# Cant login ssh with ansible because of cipher error from cisco

Tags: ansible, debian, cisco

So I am trying to automate cisco configuration in Debian OS with Ansible, the problem is when I tried to test the playbook for connection and command with:

```
ansible student1 -m raw -a  "show version | include IOS"
```

I get this error:

```
fatal: [r1]: UNREACHABLE! => changed=false
  msg: 'Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Unable to negotiate with 10.30.1.231 port 2201: no matching cipher found. Their offer: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc'
  unreachable: true
```

Is there a way to pass the cipher to Ansible? When connecting using SSH, I always use `-c aes128-cbc` and it always works out, but I dont know how Ansible handles cipher in SSH. My devices are on cisco and its in a version where pubkey-chain doesnt exist, and its not mine as well. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to pass the cipher to Ansible?

Multiple options are available.

For using [the CLI](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-playbook.html#cmdoption-ansible-playbook-ssh-common-args) add `--ssh-extra-args -c aes128-cbc`

To use a [config file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-ssh-args):

In your `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` file, set:

```sh
[ssh_connection]
-C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -c aes128-cbc
```